# If $G / \gamma_2(G)$ is finitely generated, then $\gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ is finitely generated.

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, quotient-group

I am having some difficulties proving that if $G/\gamma_2(G)$  is finitely generated, then $\gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+1}(G)$  is finitely generated. This is a well-known fact.

Assume that $G/\gamma_2(G)=\langle\overline{x_1},...,\overline{x_n}\rangle$. Further assume that $G=\langle Y\rangle$.

I know that
$$\gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+1}(G)=\langle[\overline{y_1},...,\overline{y_i}]: y_j\in Y \rangle.$$

I belive it is also true that
$$\gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+1}(G)=\langle[\overline{y_1},...,\overline{y_i}]: y_j\in \{x_1,...,x_n\} \rangle,$$
but I don't know how to show this. Could  someone give me some clue on how to startshowing this equality?

Thank you!